# How to get all the UI Element into a stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf

Am using the below function to get the topmost parent in my application.

```
private DependencyObject GetTopParent()
    {
        DependencyObject dpParent = this.Parent;
        do
        {
            dpParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(dpParent);
        } while (dpParent.GetType().BaseType != typeof(Window));
        return dpParent as DependencyObject;
    }
```

How to get all the UI Element or children into a stackpanel???
Like

```
StackPanel parentControl = this.Parent as StackPanel;
```

Comment: A little unclear what you want to do. Get all the elements from the Window and add them to a StackPanel within the Window?

Answer (score 0):

StackPanel inherits from the Panel class, which exposes a property called Children.

In other words you should have no problem accessing :

```
parentControl.Children
```

Does this help?